# from wifi to wire using a repeater

Tags: networking

I need to connect two wired devices using wifi, since I cannot connect them directly with a wire. So on the first side I placed an access point that does also wifi and acts as a dhcp server, and the first appliance is wired connected. On the other side I guess I need at least a repeater, but that can output the signal received also to the wire. Is this possible? Which appliance do you suggest me to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wireless bridge or a wireless router running a custom firmware to turn it into a bridge (DD-WRT). Any cheap wireless router that supports [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com)  or [tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) will work. I've used one of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003VY83GU) as a wireless bridge before.